# bcp import error: Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database, bcp

Using [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver15) I'm trying to import a `csv` file to an `Azure SQL Db` table. But the following command gives the error shown below:

```
bcp US_SBA_COVI19_NYS in C:\Tmp\US_SBA_COVID19.csv -S myAzuresqlserver.database.windows.net -d MySQLDb -U azure-sa -P myPassword -q -c -t ","
```

> Unexpected EOF encountered in BCP data-file

**Remarks**:

1. There are plenty of online posts on this error but none of those solutions (using `-F 2` switch, changing `-c` to `-n`, adding `-r \n or \r` etc.) worked for me. I downloaded the csv file from [here](https://catalog.data.gov/dataset?q=ppp&sort=views_recent%20desc&organization=state-of-new-york&as_sfid=AAAAAAVeDSLnoqfbKRgkNCuIbhq6cFLVnyVxjfLf5u8z5AsUWjxbPM8WS3th9rDGqHCIysM6cIKQUmFk4dRpNUbF2ZQafYVXy6jAFfLpxDuwKR8IV8QdOH8M3p9RHoIKFXzLk-E%3D&as_fid=22fe25a38777b1b408fcffec99884913befc59e1&ext_location=&ext_bbox=&ext_prev_extent=-182.8125%2C-30.751277776257812%2C-18.28125%2C72.81607371878991) on Data.gov. Maybe, the error has something to do with the file - and if someone can make it work for that file, I would like to hear about the solution.
2. I can successfully import the same `csv` to the same Db by using Import/Export wizard of SQL Server. But it needs to be done via `bcp`
3. I'm using the latest version of bcp and the Azure, and Windows-10 Pro.

**Question**: What could be a cause of the error and how can we fix it?

**UPDATE**:
In `Notepad++` I have following options for Encoding:

[image]

Comment: What's the text encoding of the .csv file? What version of bcp.exe are you attempting to use (check with `bcp.exe -v`)? Only version 13 and later support UTF-8 encoded files, for example, which you'd specify with the `-C 65001` parameter. If you're trying to deal with RFC 4180-compliant CSV files, where the fields may themselves contain commas `,`, quotes `"` and linebreak sequences, then you'll need to use [`BULK INSERT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql#format--csv) from within SQL Server 2017 or later.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning I'm using latest version `Version: 15.0.2000.5` of bcp. When opened in `Notepad++` the `csv` shows `UTF-8`.  If I specify `-C 65001` it starts asking to enter input for each column ([ref:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/specify-file-storage-type-by-using-bcp-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15)). The csv (linked in my post above) is a large file with about 100 columns and I can't tell whether it has `,` quotes `"`  or linebreak sequences. `bcp` needs to be used and BULK INSERT is not an option.

Comment: why does this need to be done via BCP? I can answer your question, but it will be an ugly solution to use BCP. the problem is the file. there's nothign 'wrong' with it, it's just not not a type of file that will load via BCP gracefully. Always, before going down the ugly path, I would ask why it MUST be BCP. Why cant this be done via SSIS package?